# Add event click to multiple buttons instance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a stacks of Bootstrap cards.

When cards are less than 10, then hide the load-more buttons.

When cards are more than 10, hide some of the cards(cards after 10 cards) - from 11th cards all cards, add css class (to hide the class).

And upon clicking the "Load-More" it should show another 10 cards - just remove the (hidden class from the cards). And hide the rest of the cards. Till now it will show 10 + 10(after click event) and hide rest of the cards(21 card onwards, to be revealed, by button click)

I can not implement this with Javascript.

If anyone can suggest any way for this.  I am looking for helpful comment to fix this.

**Edit :** I do not want to implement any **Ajax** just plain Javascript, load during page-load, and hide with `JavaScript`.

There should be multiple instances of buttons - in this example, there is four stacks of cards, and each stack should have different "load-button".

```js
window.onload = multipleCards;

function multipleCards(){
    //first find all the footer stacks, then loop through, make buttons - hide - and load function
    var stackIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("footer-card");
    var btnIndex = document.querySelectorAll(".d-grid .gap-4");
    
    //loop for all footer stacks
    for(var i=0; i<stackIndex.length; i++){
        var cardsNum = stackIndex[i].getElementsByClassName("col-6");
        if(cardsNum.length <= 10){          
            btnIndex[i].querySelector(".btn").style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            stackIndex[i].getElementsByClassName("col-6").classList.add("invisible");
            btnIndex[i].querySelector(".btn").click.classList.remove("invisible");
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Footer card - I</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - II</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - III</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - IV</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a typo in your html `class"row footer-card"` should be `class="row footer-card"`

Comment: Assuming that you have 28 cards in one 'stack', you'd expect to see the first ten cards (1-10) and a show-more button? Clicking the button you should see twenty cards (1-20), or should the first ten be hidden, and showing *only* cards 11-20? Should there be a 'show previous' button as well, or are we just adding ten to the visible 'stack' each time?

Comment: no previous button, plain - "load-button" the below example is working, but it does not work for cards more than 20. You can work standalone, or improve the exisitng one. (Bonus: spinner wheel and timeout of 300ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = multipleCards;

function loadMoreCards() {
    //Get all the invisible footer cards by index and show them
    var i = this.getAttribute("index");
    var stackIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("footer-card");
    var btnIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    var cardsNum = stackIndex[i].getElementsByClassName("card d-none");
    if(cardsNum.length<=10) {
       btnIndex[i].classList.add("d-none");
    }
    Array.from(cardsNum).slice(0, 10).forEach( function(c) { c.classList.remove("d-none"); });
}

function multipleCards() {
    //first find all the footer stacks, then loop through, make buttons - hide - and load function
    var stackIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("footer-card");
    var btnIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
    
    //loop for all footer stacks
    for(var i=0; i<stackIndex.length; i++) {
        var cardsNum = stackIndex[i].getElementsByClassName("card");
        var btn = btnIndex[i];
        if(cardsNum.length <= 10){          
            btn.classList.add("d-none");
        } else {
            Array.from(cardsNum).slice(10).forEach( function(c) { c.classList.add("d-none"); });
            btn.classList.remove("d-none");
        }
        btn.setAttribute("index", i);
        btn.addEventListener('click', loadMoreCards);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Footer card - I</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - II</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - III</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

<h3>Footer card - IV</h3>
<div class="row footer-card">
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
<div class="col-6 card"><p>This is card</p></div>
</div>

<div class="d-grid gap-4">
<button class="btn btn-secondary py-1 my-3 mx-5" type="button">Load More</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add as many classes you want for the spacing. I suggest you dont change the default classes `card` and `btn`

Comment: Spacing issue is because of your html layout and cards placement. It has nothing to do with javascript. Its out of javascript scope. Please use bootstrap classed and custom css for your desired outputs. Doing the same with JavaScript is no good thing.

Comment: @BrownPaul check now